# Get logged in user's username as twig variable

Tags: theming, 8, users

Is there a way to get the currently logged in user's username as a variable to use in any twig template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to target a specific one. All twig templates are not possible because of caching. Many page elements don't get rebuilt on every request and will display the wrong user.

And if you try to remove caching from all elements your site will be very slow.

If you add this to a specific twig template, then you can adjust the cache data of this render element:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) {
  $variables['currentusername'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername();
  $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
  $variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'user:' . \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
}
```

with the cache context to vary by user and the cache tag to invalidate the user name if the user is modified in the database. `HOOK` is your template type.

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the implementation details.